# Navigation stack error while launching

Tags: ros, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my **costmap_common_param.yaml** file i've placed these two lines :

```
observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame:base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

When i am launching my nav_pkg i get this **error** :

```
load_parameters: unable to set parameters (last param was [/move_base/TrajectoryPlannerROS/holonomic_robot=False]): cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled
```

I've been searching for a while and i **found** a **comment** which says that this error means one of the parameters is null (undefined or an empty string).  It also says to add the following line when  roslaunching the nav_pkg :

```
--dump-params
```

Indeed when i did it i found this :

```
/move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame:base_scan: null
```

But i have no ideas why is this happening and also i don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/408109/navigation-stack-error-while-launching/) by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2022-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you please try again after adding a space between `sensor_frame:` and `base_scan` as shown below:

```
laser_scan_sensor: {sensor_frame: base_scan, data_type: LaserScan, topic: scan, marking: true, clearing: true}
```

Please report if the problem persists.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kostas Tzias](https://answers.ros.org/users/108968/kostas-tzias/) on 2022-10-19**:
Yeah that worked i guess it is white space sensitive

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-10-19**:
Well, it is a YAML file, so you must use space. Anyway, I am glad that it worked. You may upvote the answer by clicking on the ^ icon located on the left side of the answer.